# sentence structure of "hopes of change to come out of the pandemic"

Tags: grammar

Just got a question when I was reading [a Guardian editorial](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2022/may/04/the-guardian-view-on-the-west-end-a-perilous-business):

> The closure of Cinderella – it may fare better on Broadway, where it
> is headed – is also a reminder of the long tail of Covid, which may
> have created the most difficult and uncertain period for the
> performing arts since the 1665 plague shut London’s playhouses. Some
> hoped that the economic disruption would precipitate more fairness and
> equality in the way cultural workers are employed. **Like many hopes of
> change to come out of the pandemic**, that seems overly optimistic. But
> the least producers could do is treat their employees with courtesy.

I am quite confused about the sentence in bold since it looks like there are two possible explanations to me:

1. Like many hopes of change // to come out of the pandemic...
2. Like many hopes of change to come // out of the pandemic...

In the first version, the "to come out of the pandemic" modifies the word "change" while the second version indicates that "change to come" should be a set phrase (just like "there are more changes to come") and "out the pandemic" modifies "hopes of change to come".

Personally, I prefer the second one but I would still like to have a closer look at the sentence.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the first one. The second phrasing leaves "out of the pandemic" in the cold. But I don't agree that "to come out of the pandemic" modifies the word "change", but "hopes of change" is a noun phrase.

Comment: "Like many [of the] hopes that change would result from the pandemic..."